# MySQL query to transfer data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mysql query to transfer data from existing table to the new one and 
I have no idea how to do it.

This is the target table keeping records for visited topics to mark them as read/unread:

```
mysql> describe topic_tracking;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| topic_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| mark_time  | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and an old one which contains the data (will be replaced by a new one)

```
mysql> describe topic_seen;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| topic_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| count    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

topic_seen.count - number of read user messages in a topic thread

```
mysql> describe topic_posts;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| topic_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| post_time | datetime         | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| user_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| txt       | text             | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I need to get the `topic_posts.post_time` for the last read message in a thread and set it as `topic_tracking.mark_time` using a `topic_seen.count`

Comment: You want to get this and update the first table with the results? select max(post_time),  topic_id,user_id  from topic_posts group by topic_id,user_id

Comment: Yes, i want set data to the first table. I need to get the time for the last read message for user.
`topic_seen.count` - a sequential number of the message of the topic.
For a specific user is the last unread message. 
All of the following post in the topic for the user are considered unread

Comment: Take a backup of the table before you try this :). I don't have a MySQL installation, so have not tested this.I still did not get the relevance of the topic_seen table. This should be the general approach     UPDATE topic_tracking SET mark_time  = (SELECT max(post_time) FROM topic_posts  WHERE topic_tracking.topic_id = topic_posts.topic_id and topic_tracking.user_id = topic_posts.user_id <put your topic_seen table and condition> )
    where (user_id ,topic_id  ) in (select  topic_id,user_id from topic_posts tp inner join topic_seen ts on s.user_id=tp.user_id and  s.topic_id=tp.topic_id)